# groupBy function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I know the Data.List module comes with the predefined function groupBy which i want to use to split a string into groups of consecutive vowels and non-vowels. the format of the function groupBy is as follows:

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

How can I use this format to do the splitting for a string? 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this

```
ghci> import Data.Char
ghci> import Data.List
ghci> groupBy (const isAlphaNum) "A bunch of words and numbers34"
["A"," bunch"," of"," words"," and"," numbers34"]
```

Or

```
ghci> groupBy (const isAlpha) "A bunch of words and numbers34"
["A"," bunch"," of"," words"," and"," numbers","3","4"]
```

**Edit:** Since there has been no indication that a solution has been found to the extended problem, in the interest of keeping up the standard of SO I shall complete the answer to the problem:

```
import Data.List

isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel c = c `elem` "aeiouy"

bothVowelConsonant :: Char -> Char -> Bool
bothVowelConsonant a b = all isVowel [a,b] || not (any isVowel [a,b])

splitByVowel :: String -> [String]
splitByVowel s = groupBy bothVowelConsonant s
```

Comment: what is "isAlphaNum" ?

Comment: I don't have any numbers in my string

Comment: Then just use ``isAlpha`` instead

Comment: that's not splitting it by vowels though...that's what my problem is

Comment: @Chalupa Stackoverflow is a question and answer site, we do not do your homework for you.  Have you considered taking my example and substituting ``isAlpha`` with a different function?

Comment: you mean i should write my own or is there a predefined one?

Comment: @Chalupa, think carefully: is grouping things by whether or not they are vowels in English something that's really likely to be of sufficient general utility to bother putting in a package intended for public use?

Comment: @Chalupa If you are still lost for an answer, then see my edits and review your haskell.

Comment: @randomusername I usually blame the hardware. Or sunspots. ;-)